# List as Property in Class

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
public class Items
{
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
}
public class Orders
{
    public List<Items> ItemList { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to create an instance of the order object, the ItemList property initialization throws a null error saying that the get property of ItemList is null. The error is thrown at `orders.ItemList.Add(itm)` line. The answer might be obvious and simple, but I can't see it. Here is the code:

```
Orders orders = new Orders();
for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
{
    Items itm = new Items
    {
        ItemName = $"Item {i}"
    };
    orders.ItemList.Add(itm);
}
```

What silly mistake am I making here?

Comment: The mistake you're making is that you're not initializing the `ItemList` property, so it will be `null`, and you can't do `.Add(itm)` on a null reference.

Comment: there is no default value and no construct, thus its null

Comment: `orders.ItemList = new List<Items>();`

Comment: Generally speaking, class names should not be plural unless they represent a collection. So your classes should be called `Item` and `Order`, and the list property on `Order` should be `Items`. Also, it's usually not recommended to include the class name as part of a property name, so the `ItemName` property should just be `Name` (it's a little redundant to do `item.ItemName` instead of just `item.Name`)

Comment: @Rufus Thanks for the note. Appreciate that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to initialize the ItemsList, therefore you get a nullpointer exception

```
public class Orders
{
    public List<Items> ItemList { get; set; } = new List<Items>();
}
```

Comment: Perfect. That worked. What a silly mistake that I am making!

Comment: It is normal, specially if you are a beginner. Try to understand the problem, and next time you won't fail again :) Don't forget to mark the answer as correct

Answer (score 3):

Your not initializing the property so it is null.

Try this:

```
public class Orders
{
    public List<Items> ItemList { get; set; } = new List<Items>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The property is set to whatever it's default is, in this case `null`. You probably want to set it in the constructor, and make the setter private so it can't be set to `null` later.

```
public class Orders
{
    public Orders()
    {
        ItemList = new List<Items>();
    }

    public List<Items> ItemList { get; private set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

List has not been initialized with a new instance of List.

```
orders.ItemList = new List<Items>();
```

Code will look like this:

```
Orders orders = new Orders();
orders.ItemList = new List<Items>();
for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
{
    Items itm = new Items
    {
        ItemName = $"Item {i}"
    };
    orders.ItemList.Add(itm);
}
```